# Invalid (Aborted)core dumped error while using free() in C

Tags: c, pointers, free

here's the code:
can anyone explain this issue
how can i deallocate the memory of s in main

```
char *get(int N)
{
    char *s=malloc(10*sizeof(char));  
    s="hello";  
    return s;  
}
 int main()  
{  
    char *s=get(4);  
    printf(s);  
    free(s);  
}
```

Comment: You're reassigning the pointer value of `s` to a static string and not actually storing "hello" into the malloc'ed memory like you think. Therefore you're free-ing non-allocated memory

Comment: `strcpy(s,"hello");`

Comment: `char *s=get(6);`

Comment: Pouring salt on the wound called out by @sshashank124 above, you're also leaking memory.

Comment: @P__J__ if `N` was used for anything :-)

Comment: great! But what if i want to assign N number of chars(ie.,based on argument passed) to the string s inside get function?(cant use strcpy?)

Comment: regarding the expression:  `sizeof(char)`   this is defined in the C standard as 1 multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: rather than `strcpy()`,  you could use `strncpy()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This here:

```
s="hello";
```

Doesn't write `"hello"` to the allocated memory. Instead, it reassigns `s` to point to a read-only place where `"hello"` is stored. The memory you allocated with `malloc` is leaked, and the `free(s);` is invalid, because you can't free that read-only memory.

If you want to copy `"hello"` into `s`, try `strcpy(s,"hello");` instead.

Comment: great! But what if i want to assign N number of chars(ie.,based on argument passed) to the string s inside get function?

Comment: You can use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) to limit the amount of characters copied.

Comment: To be specific i want to copy alphabets starting from 'a' till N .So should i store it in a char array and the copy it to malloced string? but this wastes some memory

Comment: Yeah, i'd still do it that way. Most likely those 26 bytes won't make a big difference, and they're likely in the program's binary either way. You could assemble the alphabet with a loop that keeps adding to `'a'` (for instance, `'a' + 1` is `b`), but that would be complicated, most likely slower and might not even save any memory. Hardcoding the alphabet is probably the best solution here.

Comment: Or you can use `s = strdup("hello");` that will do the allocation and the copy in one shot.  Then, you can call `free(s);` if you don't do the mistake of assigning `s` another value.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
s="hello";
```

you're overwriting the returned pointer by `malloc()` with the pointer to the first element of the string literal `"hello"`, which is not allocated dynamically.

Next, you are passing that pointer (to a string literal) to `free()`, which causes the undefined behavior.

You may want to change the assignment to

```
strcpy(s, "hello");
```

Additionally, by overwriting the originally returned pointer by `malloc()`, you don't have a chance to deallocate the memory - so you also cause memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs here:

1. You reassign the pointer `s` with the reference of the string literal "hello", loosing the memory allocated by `malloc`
2. You allocate not enough space for the "hello" string. You need at least 6 characters (not 4)

Comment: Not nitpicking, the actual problem in __this__ code is elsewhere, which is pointed out by two other answer, and missing in yours.

Comment: (1) the problem is not with reassigning, rather passing invalid pointer to free  and (2) notice, the argument value is not used in this code, so point 2 is not a valid reason here.

Comment: @SouravGhosh no - it is not elsewhere - the main problem is my point 1.

Comment: OK, if you say so. I'll stop commenting now.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The assignment is the source of the problem. The free is the effect.

Comment: argument passed to `get(int N)` has no role in allocated memory. `malloc` is done for 10 `char` and hence point:2 is not right.

Comment: @P__J__ parameter `N` is not used so your second point doesn't make sense.

Comment: great! But what if i want to assign N number of chars(ie.,based on argument passed) to the string s inside get function?(cant use strcpy?)

Comment: Yes you can, everything is the same except instead of using the operator `=` witch is an assignment, you use `strcpy()` witch copies the string `"hello"` to the location referenced by `s`.

Answer (score 0):

A variable of type `char *` is a pointer (memory address) to a character. In C, it is customary to implement strings as zero-terminated character arrays and to handle strings by using variables of type `char *` to the first element of such an array.

That way, variables of type `char *` do not actually contain the strings, they merely point to them.

For this reason, the line

`s="hello";`

does not actually copy the contents of the string, but rather only the pointer (i.e. the memory address) of the string.

If you want to copy the actual contents of the string, you must use the function [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) instead.

By overwriting the pointer that you use to store the address of the memory allocated by `malloc`, you are instead passing the address of the string literal `"hello"` to `free`. This should not be done. You must instead only pass memory addresses to `free` that you received from `malloc`.